# Copy storage from android to PC via USB to recover deleted photos from android

Tags: python, android, windows

I want to copy the whole content of the storage from my android phone (byte by byte). When I connect my phone to the PC, it appears as a device, therefore there is no Drive letter associated with it and I am not sure how to access the storage.

I have only gone as far as to find the device ID. I am not sure how to move forward. Googling didn't help.

The reason I want this is to try to retrieve some deleted files from my phone. Unfortunately, most of the retrieval tools do not support devices (they simply do not appear) and the ones that are supporting android phones, do not work, so I thought copying the whole storage to another drive.

Comment: I don't think you can get all `byte by byte` using `USB` - it may need rather to run some code directly on Android to access its API/functions which can read data directly from storage

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of search, I couldn't find how to do it from a PC.

A solution to the main problem is to download an app that can recover deleted files. Not all apps are good, one that I found working very well is [Photo Recovery:Recover Deleted Photo Data Recovery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=recover.deleted.data.mobile.data.recovery.app.diskdigger) which has very few adds and did the trick fast without any issues. and does not require rooting.